# Celery daemon service is not triggering target function on schedule basis in Django

Tags: python, django, celery

celery.py under main project MAP/map

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from django.apps import apps

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', map.settings')
app = Celery("Celery App")
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: [app.name for app in apps.get_app_configs()])

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    
    'load_trafic_attendance': {
        'task': traffic.tasks.load_traffic_data',
        'schedule': crontab(minute="*/10")
    },
}
```

task function under traffic app in task.py file

```
@app.task(name=traffic.tasks.load_traffic_data')
def load_traffic_data():
……………………
……………………
```

celery.conf file under script app

```
# Celery configuration options
CELERY_BIN="/home/sam/MAP/env/bin/celery"
CELERY_APP="map"
CELERYD_NODES="worker beat"
CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/sam/MAP/"
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/home/sam/logs/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/home/sam/run/%n.pid"
```

celery.service file in /etc/systemd/system/ dir

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=sam
Group=sam
WorkingDirectory=/home/sam/MAP/
EnvironmentFile=/home/sam/MAP/scripts/celery.conf
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /home/sam/logs; chown sam:sam /home/sam/logs;  mkdir -p /home/sam/run; chown sam:sam /home/sam/run'
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} {CELERYD_OPTS}'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The above setup does not call the load_traffic_data function at all though it should be called in every 10 minutes. However when we run two debug commands on shell after entering into virtual env it calls the function at every 10 minutes. what I am missing here to daemonize the service?

two debug command are:

```
celery -A map beat --loglevel=debug
And 
celery -A map worker --loglevel=debug
```

Comment: you need to perform all these check, i feel the error is in the configuartion